# JavaScript snippets in Code Snippets Manager not showing up in Intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, code-snippets, javascript-intellisense

In Visual Studio 2019, I have imported a snippet using Tools -> Code Snippets Manager per the [Microsoft Walkthrough documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019).

I can see it in Code Snippets Manager.

[image]

Here is the content of my snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>switch</Title>
      <Author>Me</Author>
      <Description>Inserts a switch case.</Description>
      <Shortcut>cmswitch</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="JavaScript">
        <![CDATA[ switch ($switch_on$) {case 0: break; default:}]]>
      </Code>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>switch_on</ID>
          <ToolTip>Enter the switch case criteria.</ToolTip>
          <Default>switch_on</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

When I try to use the snippet by typing `cm` in a basic `.cshtml` file, I get nothing.

[image]

Any idea why my snippet is not showing up in intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In fact, it is an issue on VS2019.** I also have the same behavior in my side with VS2019.

The **Code Snippets Manager** listed the code snippet which proves that VS has enabled that snippet. I can even insert code snippets manually and it seems that the shortcut does not work on VS2019.

**However**, when I tested the issue on VS2017. It can works well. So I am curious whether the issue is related to **VS2019** itself.

**VS2017**:

[image]

[I have reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1285185/why-javascript-code-snippet-shortcut-cannot-work-o.html). And you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

**And** since the process might take a long time, you have to right-click on the code editor-->**Insert Snippet** to add your own snippet manually to get what you want.

====================================

**Update 1**

[report the issue on forum again](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1303633/why-javascript-code-snippet-shortcut-cannot-work-o-1.html).

Comment: Thank you for logging it in the Microsoft forums.  I have added some supporting tests of aspx, js, cshtml, and html files.  None of which work with the snippet for javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And this is a real issue on VS2019 while I used it well on VS2017. Since we cannot do any other things here, I suggest you could accept this answer to let other community members know it is a real issue. And I will follow the DC problem and let you know any reponse.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for the help!  I hope they can fix it.

Comment: I also raised a new ticket here.[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1289365/why-shortcut-for-js-snippet-does-not-work-on-vs201.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1289365/why-shortcut-for-js-snippet-does-not-work-on-vs201.html).

Comment: @cmill, the `switch` title of your code snippet has a conflict with the system code snippet. Please reanme the title like `JSswitch` and then restart VS. I could find the `cmswitch`.